# I am capturing Eventhub logs into a storage account but it shows in avro encoding format. I am expecting in Json

Tags: azure-eventhub

I am capturing Eventhub logs in to storage account for cold storage. But it shows me in "Avro" format. I want it to be logged in JSON format. Please suggest how can it be done, without an extra step to convert AVRO to JSON

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. The Avro format is by design and cannot be changed. The only way is that convert Avro to json.

Comment: @Shanky, hello, if the answer is helpul, could you please help mark it as answer as per this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top), thanks.